# Java BigDecimal setScale and rounding with half_even

Tags: java

I am using the following code with the java BigDecimal setScale method with half_even rounding mode and am getting the following results.

```
new BigDecimal(1.115).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).toPlainString()
```

Result: 1.11

Expected: 1.12

Since the closest even digit to the left to 5 should be 2 the result I would expect is 1.12. But the result is 1.11. And again,

```
new BigDecimal(1.145).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).toPlainString()
```

Result: 1.15

Expected: 1.14

Because the even digit to the left of 5 is 4 I would expect the result to be 1.14. Any explanation for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by floating point imprecisions (in your `double` input value).

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(1.115));

1.1149999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375
```

Use the String constructor instead.

```
BigDecimal.valueOf("1.115")
```

Once the number is a BigDecimal, no precision is lost and rounding works properly.
But you have to make sure the number gets into the BigDecimal intact (and has not already lost precision before that by forcing it through a floating point type).

Comment: How do I apply the setScale method to set the scale and round off in this case?

Comment: You use `setScale` just like in your code. And it works then (I tested). The rounding works properly with BigDecimal. Your problem is that the floating point you put into BigDecimal was already broken (slighly off the rounding point).

Comment: There's no need to cast it to String and use BigDecimal.valueOf(String value); BigDecimal.valueOf(double value) works as expected too!