# java rounding error using half_even for x.715 and x.915

Tags: java

when using `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN`  (default) for `java.text.DecimalFormat`, I see an anomaly in return values.

I realize that there is precision error, See:
[Java BigDecimal setScale and rounding with half_even](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27141899/java-bigdecimal-setscale-and-rounding-with-half-even)

However since this is `java.text.DecimalFormat` I expected that would be handled

Definition:

```
HALF_EVEN
Rounding mode to round towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even neighbor.
```

This is the example, to check double rounding:

```java
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] dStrings= new String[] { "1548.015", "1548.115", "1548.215", "1548.515", "1548.715", "1548.815", "1548.915",    "1548.705", "1548.715", "1548.725", "1548.755", "1548.775", "1548.785", "1548.795",   "1548.710", "1548.711", "1548.712", "1548.715", "1548.717", "1548.718", "1548.719" } ;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

        Double dValue;
        System.out.println("round mode:half_even...");
        System.out.println("String   => str-frmt| dec-frmt");
        //df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
        for (String dStr : dStrings) {
            //dValue = new Double(dStr);
            //dValue = Double.parseDouble(dStr);
            dValue = Double.valueOf(dStr);
            System.out.println(String.format("%s => %.2f | BD: %s |DF %s", dStr, dValue, BigDecimal.valueOf(dValue).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN), df.format(dValue) ));
        }
    }
}
```

4rd value is rounded using `java.text.DecimalFormat`, 1st value is original

```
1548.015 => 1548.02 | BD: 1548.02 |DF 1548.02
1548.115 => 1548.12 | BD: 1548.12 |DF 1548.12
1548.215 => 1548.22 | BD: 1548.22 |DF 1548.21 - not ok
1548.515 => 1548.52 | BD: 1548.52 |DF 1548.52
1548.715 => 1548.72 | BD: 1548.72 |DF 1548.71 - not ok
1548.815 => 1548.82 | BD: 1548.82 |DF 1548.82
1548.915 => 1548.92 | BD: 1548.92 |DF 1548.91 - not ok
```

nearest neighbor is 1 each case listed above and 5 is equidistant, correct? so all these cases round should have gone to 2, correct?

I tested on multiple current and past JDK versions, all came with same results. Am I misunderstanding or is this a bug? please explanation why `java.text.DecimalFormat` is not mindful of floating point precision, as that appears to be the problem.

Also why is the basic rounding model, used in String.format `'%.2f'`, not represented in `java.math.RoundingMode`?  i.e. rounding up nearest neighbor when 5 and above.

Comment: You should construct BigDecimal directly from the corresponding Strings, not from Double. When you convert a String 1548.915 into double the result is not a precise 1548.915  but a little bit smaller.

Comment: @Tepal You are correct. I was missing your point. With your suggested example of `1548.715` (and other values) it does see that rounding to a decimal fraction is *not* respecting HALF_EVEN rounding rules. I found this mysterious behavior under Java 12 and Java 17. I have no explanation. I am deleting my Answer. And using `BigDecimal` is the way to go to avoid these problems, when you value accuracy.

Comment: See this simplified example [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/qWvHeW) where I successfully use `DecimalFormat` with rounding HALF_EVEN (by default) for values 71.5d and 7.15d but the value 0.715 fails.

Comment: rounding floating points is never going to be reliable according to Oracle's response,   so only reliable option is to use the string format operations as given in my example.  All the complications of rounding using BigDecimal are meaningless if it is wrong even once, this is why rockets fail.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out complex, the short of it is that floating point based rounding cannot be relied upon, and the behavior seen is correct, just as Basil had indicated.  When rounding input, you should not use a floating point.

best solution, is the easiest and obvious use of example: String.format("%s => %.2f", strDecimal)

**Oracle SR response:**

JDK7 is buggy behavior (please see JDK-7131459), and.JDK8 is the correct behavior.

The problem is that "0.5555", which we all understand as the decimal value 0.5555 cannot be represented in any binary representation (including IEEE-754).
The most precise binary representation of this number that can be obtained is 0.55549999999999999378275106209912337362766265869140625 .
One can get this best possible approximation using BigDecimal which provides infinite precision:

System.out.println("BigDecimal output for 0.5555: " + new BigDecimal(0.5555).toString());

The above will return:
"BigDecimal output for 0.5555 : 0.55549999999999999378275106209912337362766265869140625"

Thus we can see that the closest binary representation for 0.5555 is a bit less than 0.5555 (0.555499.....).

So even if programmer intents to use decimal 0.5555, the computer works with the best approximation from IEEE-754,
which is something like 0.5554999999999999... Again this is less than 0.5555 decimal value.

Under HALF-EVEN rounding rule, when rounding at the 3rd fractional digit after decimal point, which is the case in the above program,
no rounding up of this fractional digit should happen, and the correct result here is "55.5%"

JDK7 is wrong here, JDK8 is correct.

Correct JDK7 behavior can be obtained when using -XX:+AggressiveOpts option (starting 7u14-b13).

*** It is very important to understand that almost all floating-point values cannot be recorded exactly by any binary representation (like IEEE-754 here).
With floating-point what you see is not what you get !

### Doc for reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/800-7895/800-7895.pdf

Based on what I found and also the information I got from other engineers,
this is not an issue with java 8 and up, but an expected behavior about the floating decimal.
The implementation is based on IEEE-754 standard.